# Stderr sometimes gets redirected to /dev/null

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, prezto

Sometimes when i am working in a shell i suddenly find out that standard error has been linked to /dev/null. If i open a new shell it is back to normal.

I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh and prezto. I have looked over the rc files but i cannot find any reason why this should happen seemingly at random.

Comment: I wonder if a program/script is setting: `exec 2>/dev/null` somewhere

Comment: Also, it would be useful to know how you find out exactly

Comment: See https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/547